# Как создавать и заполнять динамический массив?

Tags: c++, массивы

Как создавать динамический массив?
Как заполнять массив сразу при создании?

Comment: Говоря о **динамическом** Вы имеете в виду, что размер в процессе работы может меняться, или он не известен до запуска программы, а однажды выделенный уже не меняется ?

Answer (score 1):

В стиле С++ для данных типа type:

```
type * ptr = new type [number];
```

Освобождение памяти:

```
delete [] ptr;
```

Заполнять - через цикл, например.

В стиле С:

```
type * ptr = (type*) malloc (number*sizeof(type));
type * ptr = (type*) calloc (number, sizeof(type));
```

calloc() отличается тем, что сам заполняет выделенную память нулями.
Освобождение памяти:

```
free (ptr);
```

P.S. Вообще-то, это все содержится в любом учебнике.

Answer (score 0):

malloc() когда места для новых уже нет realloc() (может быть несколько раз в цикле).

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно использовать готовый класс vector. Он расширяется при добавлении в него элементов.

Comment: Можно... но пока еще рано